# Rails Rspec cannot access a GET route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rspec, haml

I set the route GET "remove_photo" like this:

```
  resources :profile do
    get "remove_photo"
    get "remove_letter"
    get "remove_statement"
    get "remove_resume"
    get "remove_others"
  end
```

Then I have my controller with the method remove_photo:

```
  def remove_photo
    @cur_user ||= Account.find_by_session_token(session[:session_token])   # for testing
    @profile = Profile.find_by_account_id @cur_user.id
    byebug
    @profile.remove_photo!
    @profile.save!
    # end
    redirect_to edit_profile_path(@profile)
  end
```

This works well on the related haml view page to call the remove_photo method with profile_remove_photo_path(@profile)

```
    = link_to 'delete file', profile_remove_photo_path(@profile)
```

However, when I was trying to do rspec testing on the remove_photo method, it failed to call the profile_remove_photo_path(@profile) method:

```
  describe 'test remove photo method' do
    it 'remove photo successfully' do
      fake_user = double('User')
      allow(Account).to receive(:find_by_session_token).and_return(fake_user)

      fake_profile = double('Profile')
      allow(Profile).to receive(:find_by_account_id).and_return(fake_profile)
      allow(fake_user).to receive(:id).and_return(fake_profile)

      allow(fake_profile).to receive(:remove_photo!)
      allow(fake_profile).to receive(:save!)

      # post profile_remove_photo_path(1)
      get profile_remove_photo_path(1)
      expect(response).to redirect_to edit_profile_path(1)
    end
  end
```

```
Failures:

  1) ProfileController test remove photo method remove photo successfully
     Failure/Error: get profile_remove_photo_path(1)
     
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/profile/1/remove_photo", :controller=>"profile"}
     # ./spec/controllers/profile_controller_spec.rb:116:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I really don't understand why the method is called successfully in my haml view, but does not work in the rspec. Thanks so much for any ideas.

My attempts are shown above.

Comment: That isn't a very good way to define your routes. GET should be idempotent and not create or destroy resources. Instead you should define it as `delete "photo"` or `resource :photo, only: [ :destroy ]`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: Thanks for the response. The photo is not a separate model, but only an attribute in the Profile model. Can I still use the resource :photo?

Comment: Yes. Resources don't not have to correspond to models. Models are just the internal implementation details of an application. The routes are the API that your app provides to the outside world.

Comment: Additionally since you're not actually using the ID parameter you should just define it as a singular route -  `resource :profile`. Which would give you `/profile` and `/profile/photo`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have tried changing the code to be ```delete "photo"```, but still my app works to call ```profile_remove_photo_path```, but the rspec fails. The error message is the same -- no route matches. 
I even tried  ```rake routes``` in terminal, which clearly listed my route.

Answer (score 0):

Finally realized my issue. It turned out that I am not having enough knowledge about rspec. I should not call the path `profile_remove_photo_path` in here, instead I should directly call the method `:remove_photo`!!
My rspec is like this now. (I changed the route method from `get` to `delete` according to @max)

```
  describe 'test remove photo method' do
    it 'remove photo successfully' do
      fake_user = double('User')
      allow(Account).to receive(:find_by_session_token).and_return(fake_user)

      fake_profile = double('Profile')
      allow(Profile).to receive(:find_by_account_id).and_return(fake_profile)
      allow(fake_user).to receive(:id).and_return(fake_profile)

      allow(fake_profile).to receive(:remove_photo!)
      allow(fake_profile).to receive(:save!)

      # delete profile_remove_photo_path     # rspec should not call the path in rspec!! should call the method!!!
      delete :remove_photo, {:profile_id => 1}          # directly use delete + method, done!!

      # # this line below can recognize path
      # Rails.application.routes.recognize_path profile_remove_photo_path(1)      # Rails recognize this path!
      expect(response).to redirect_to edit_profile_path(fake_profile)

    end
  end
```

Comment: That implies that you're writing a controller spec. The use of controller specs are is discouraged by both the Rails and RSpec teams and its known to be an extremely flawed method of testing your application. If you add in the fact that you're stubbing out the entire database interaction then you're barely actually testing your application at all here. https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html

Comment: Find better more up to date tutorials and write request, feature and system specs. Controller specs have no place outside of legacy code.